# What is the largest database of denominations of Christianity?

Tags: denomination-survey

[This Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominations) lists many (hundreds of?) Christian denominations. But then there is the [40k denomination claim](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63368/what-is-the-source-of-the-count-of-40000-denominations-and-how-are-they-classif). Are there any more robust lists or databases cataloging the Christian denominations? I would like to know the names of the 40k+ denominations basically. Ideally these would be freely available datasets, but if not, that would be good to know too (and at least where the private data is located).

Comment: other sources: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/56053/22319

Comment: I should also mention that the 40k is probably overinflated, the closer number is still pretty high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [World Christian Database](https://worldchristiandatabase.org) seems to be the most popular. It contains information on most (if not all) Christian denominations and religions.

Comment: That is a paid database, do you know of any free ones, even if they are partial?

Comment: @Lance [This](https://www.thearda.com/conQS/) link should have what you are looking for